# finding double dashes in vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find all double dashes in a text (tex) file that aren't triple dashes.

To this end, I put `[^-]--[^-]` in the find-field (`Ctrl+f`, not the sidebar) with regexp mode activated. However, this fails to match double dashes at the beginning or end of a line.

I have two questions:

1. What's an elegant way to fix the regular expression to also match double dashes at line boundaries?
2. Is there a vscode option that changes the find behaviour in a way that forces my regexp to have the desired effect? I read something about multiline regular expressions, but that seemed only to work when explicitly including `\n` in the regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[^-]` consumes a single char other than `-`

If you only want to match `--` you can use lookarounds asserting not - to the left and right.

```
(?<!-)--(?!-)
```

[image]

Comment: nice! this one doesn't even require special treatment of beginning and end of line

Answer (score 2):

try this. Just need a start and end in an or declaration:

```
 (^|[^-])--([^-]|$)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I won't accept your answer for now, to see if I can get an answer to my second question

Comment: @lejlun for my purposes it doesn't matter, but indeed the solution of The fourth bird  using lookahead and lookbehind avoids this problem